# Can't get rid of an Adfoc.us redirect virus

Tags: malware, antivirus

My Android seems to be infected with a very nasty virus. Sometimes when I open links to totally safe pages (like stackoverflow) from my mobile I got redirected to a page called adfoc.us (adfoc.us/serve/?id=25497650908175) that then tries to download files like MoboMarket.apk that seem to be malware.

I tried running MalwareBytes but it only detected the .apk files that were downloaded. I tried running Avast, but I did not detect anything.

What else can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: This could be a problem with your internet connection, instead of the phone itself. What kind of connection are you using?

Comment: It has happened when I've been using wifi and when I've been using 3g. It happened when I was in holidays and here in London, so I think it's my phone.

Comment: I'd suggest a factory reset.

Comment: Would that make me lose all my applications data?

Comment: Yes. You should back up anything important first.